# Paramiko does not work inside Django when grequests is loaded

Tags: python, django, paramiko

I have a django site. Once page makes use of Grequests. This is preventing any of the other pages that use Paramiko from functioning. How can I get around this?

The error it throws is:

```
Error reading SSH protocol bannerThis operation would block forever
```

Comment: Are you running your python script on the same server as the django development one?

Comment: Yes I am. Its running as the same user as well.