# Conflict between grequests / gevent and sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, gevent, ssh-tunnel, grequests

I'm working on a web scraper that makes use of `grequests`, and then `sshtunnel` to store the data in a database.

However importing `grequests` and `sshtunnel` causes `Error reading SSH protocol banner cannot switch to a different thread`

If `grequests` is imported nothing will work, without it being imported the `sshtunnel` works perfectly. It's not possible to remove `grequests`. I've tried with and without monkeypatch, the result is the same.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
import grequests
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel
```

I've found a small number of mentions online about conflicts between `gevent` and `paramiko (sshtunnel)` but no solutions.

[Paramiko does not work inside Django when grequests is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041310/paramiko-does-not-work-inside-django-when-grequests-is-loaded)

[pysftp, paramiko, grequests: Error reading SSH protocol banner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288526/pysftp-paramiko-grequests-error-reading-ssh-protocol-banner)

However none of these are exactly the same error, and none of them solve the problem.

Has anyone encountered this and/or found a workaround?

I don't need any parallel `ssh` connections in the code, just one connection at the start to load current data, and one at the end to dump the new data. This problem happens as soon as `grequests` is imported, it doesn't have to be used anywhere.